# Hostgator ip server gives me error 404

Tags: php, android, web-hosting

I am a new android developer and I just finished my log in and registration pages using php and json with android studio, all that done and works fine on localhost.

Then I move all my php files and db to hostgator hosting and I changed the db user and password in my `config.php` file but I kept the host as localhost, but when I try run log in page on my app it disable me to log in while the input data is correct. I do not what is the wrong it took from me on week with out find solution.

Btw when I put my ip server of hostgator it gives me error 404 but when I put the domain name it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a dedicated server. It's a host. So many domains use the same IP. It means that you cannot use IP only. you have to use domain name only.